# Web Service Listener in Android

Tags: android, web-services, notifications

I am newbie in Android Development. I am trying to create listener in Android application which will show notification. My web service returns 1/0 as an output.

I am trying to create a listener in my android app which will keep listening to this web service and show notification to user if value is 0.

Any help or direction in this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "Google Cloud Messaging for Android", although still to figure out how to use it.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#push-process